# Explain expressions "better down", "out on their luck"

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

I really want to know the meaning of the following sentence:

> There ain't nobody dancing who looked better down and out on their luck.

I can only translate the sentence to "There isn't anybody dancing." But I don't know what "better down" and "out on their luck" mean.

The sentence is taken from a song named "High Society" by singer Betty Who.

Comment: Where did these sentences come from? ...  Oh, it's rap song lyrics.  I think interpretation of song lyrics is off topic.

Comment: Unless there is some context joining the two sentences, I think you should ask these as two separate questions.

Comment: Thank you. I'll post another question for the second sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is tricky to parse because [*down and out*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/down-and-out) is a fixed expression.  It means poor, destitute, hopeless, and socially outcast.

You wouldn't expect a poor person to dance gracefully, but this sentence talks about someone who manages to look good despite being poor.

Comment: I also found out that "to be down on luck" means that ["to be suffering because a lot of bad things are happening to you](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+down+on+luck)".